# How to get the value from the `ul li` and write in another `ul li`

Tags: jquery, html, css

Question: 1

I am having two `ul li` elements which will fetch and write the values from one to another.its like writing values from  `li a` to another `li b` using jquery `html` function. Everything works fine, despite i need to write only the first 5 characters.

Question : 2

I am have a progress bar which the bar will fills up for each step. For the initial stage the meter will neither go forward nor backward and even the navigation doest work. On filling each step the progress meter will expand and the navigation will add a class `active`. So once Iam in step 2 or further all i need to enable the navigation for only the steps which I have completed its just like I can go back and edit the details which I completed already.

So here is the code

```
$('article:not(:last-child) ul li, .continue').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('article').hide().next().fadeIn('slow');
    var index = $('article').index();
    $('.subnav-tabs>.row>.active').find('b').text($(this).find('a').html());

    $(".progress-meter>span").animate({
        "width": "+=20%",
    }, "slow").promise().done(function() {
        $('.subnav-tabs>.row>.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    });

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/91m965L0/1/)**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Re Question 1: Huh? Can you please clarify. Do you only wish to copy the first 5 characters from the LI clicked to the menu item?

Comment: Re: question 2: How do you go backwards? Is the progress bar meant to act like a menu and take you back to previous `articles`?

Comment: No the progress bar is not a menu at all its reacts according to menu above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit hard to determine requirements, but here is my stab at it.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/91m965L0/3/

```
$('article:not(:last-child) ul li, .continue').click(function () {
    var $li = $(this);

    // Hide current article and show the next
    var $article = $li.closest('article');
    $article.hide().next().fadeIn('slow');

    // Get index of selected article
    var index = $article.index();

    // Copy the text to the matching slot
    $('.subnav-tabs .row div').eq(index).find('b').text($li.text().substr(0, 5));

    $(".progress-meter>span").animate({
        "width": ((index+1) * 20) + "%",
    }, "slow").promise().done(function () {
        $('.subnav-tabs .row div').eq(index).addClass('active').nextAll();
    });

});

$('.subnav-tabs').on('click', 'div.active', function () {
    var $item = $(this);
    $('article').eq($item.index()).fadeIn('slow').siblings('article').hide();
});
```

The code has been changed to use the parallel index values of the menus and articles to keep them in sync. The progress bar now calculates the end position based on the selection, and not progressively add 20%. You may want to modify this behavior as going backwards will reduce the completion %.

Note: you need to have a common ancestor for the articles in order for `index` to give 0-based indexes (it included the menu divs in the original).